# Replacing Mint 15 With Ubuntu gnome 13.04

Tags: gnome, mint

Is there a way of replacing Mint 15 with Ubuntu Gnome 13 and keeping all my files?

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you did a separate partition for your /home, then in the manual instalation in the cd/usb images just install ubuntu over mint and select to not format /home.

If you did not creat a separate partition for home you will have to copy all of it or just the data you are interested.